# Leaflet markers not displaying

Tags: leaflet, mapbox

What is wrong with my code?

```
Template = {    
    render : function(){

        if (!Map.map){
            Map.create_map();
            Map.set_tile_layer();
        }
        
        API.get_businesses();
    }
}
API = {
    get_businesses : function(){
        $.ajax({
            url : '/api/mapviz_get_businesses',
            type: 'GET',
            datatype: 'json',
            data: {},
            success: function(d){
                $(d).each(function(i, item){
                    var marker = L.marker([item.coords.coordinates[0], item.coords.coordinates[1]]).addTo(Map.map)
                })
            }
        })
    }
}
Map = {
    map : null,
    create_map : function(){
        Map.map = L.map('map').setView(
            [32.7766642,-96.79698789999998],5);
    },  
    set_tile_layer : function(){
        L.tileLayer('https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/{id}/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token={accessToken}', {
            attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, Imagery © <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>',
            maxZoom: 18,
            id: 'mikejohnsonjr/ckmbpaffj6dmw17s3h4ll5wje',
            tileSize: 512,
            zoomOffset: -1,
            accessToken: 'pk.eyJ1IjoibWlrZWpvaG5zb25qciIsImEiOiJjaWY5dXJ4bnAxaXVnc3VrbnpocXd3MXF5In0.iVbz_2py7DdmvpoQTzVe0A'
        }).addTo(Map.map);
    }
}

Template.render()
```

The map loads but the markers do not, not even when I open up console and do the L.marker() function manually.

Can anyone help?

I'm following this very simple guide and cannot see where I'm going wrong: https://leafletjs.com/examples/quick-start/

Everything returned by the ajax function is fine.

Comment: There are two possibilities that might cause this: either your marker coordinates are in some projected CRS or order in which you specify coordinates is wrong. Have in mind that Leaflet has coordinate order [lat, lng].

Comment: I tried using coordinates from the example linked and that didn't work either

Comment: What do you mean by "coordinates from the example"? Coordinates from example (`[51.508, -0.11]`) are way off your map view center `[32.7766642,-96.79698789999998]`. Have you checked coordinate order in your marker definition call?

Comment: coordinates from this example: https://leafletjs.com/examples/quick-start/